# Android Wear 2.0 Share Screen

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to share the display of my LG Style watch to a PC for an app demonstration. I haven't been able to find anything online mentioning this. Does anyone know how this might be done?

Thank you

Comment: https://rominirani.com/tutorial-cast-your-android-wear-screen-to-all-5265c392007b or juste use an emulator for the demo ?

Comment: It needs to be connected to a phone/tablet and another watch so I don't think we could use an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [tutorial](https://rominirani.com/tutorial-cast-your-android-wear-screen-to-all-5265c392007b) on how to Cast your Android Wear Screen. Make sure that you have setup the Android SDK on your machine. Specifically, you need to be aware where you have setup your Android SDK and Tools and are aware of the adb command.

> **Steps:**
>
> 1. Enable Developer Options on your Android Wear device.
> 2. Enable Debugging over Bluetooth on your Android Phone.
> 3. Enable ADB Debugging on your Android Wear Device.
> 4. Fire up a few ADB Commands.
> 5. Verify that both Android Device and Wear Device appear in the ADB devices.
> 6. Use any of the ADB Screen Casting Tools

Hope this helps!